# How do I kill a session in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

It appears that Symfony2 is waiting for AJAX response after a request. It will not go to another link on the same page until the response comes back.

This article describes the problem:
http://garethmccumskey.blogspot.com/2009/10/php-session-write-locking-and-how-to.html

I cannot find a solution in Symfony2 though.

Answer (score 14):

After reading the blog post you are referring to and reading the code of the `Session` and `NativeSessionStorage` classes, what I would try to mimic the behavior mentionned in the blog post is to do this:

```
$session = $this->get('session');

// Change the session attributes

$session->save();
session_write_close();

// Do database calls and other stuff.
```

I didn't test it but it should work as expected. Another solution to your problem is to use a different session storage than the `NativeSessionStorage` which is used by default. You could use for example a database storage by using the `PdoSessionStorage` object. This could prevent a lock from being use by PHP. See this [cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) for more information on how to use a database storage for sessions.

But there is no guarantee that the database system won't stack multiple requests if they are accessing the same row but it should be way faster than with the `NativeSessionStorage`.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: If you don't mind I quoted your solution in this blog post : http://blog.alterphp.com/2012/08/how-to-deal-with-asynchronous-request.html. Let me know if you're annoyed...

Comment: You may omit session_write_close(); because session service save() method will call NativeSessionStorage save() method and it has session_write_close(); already. http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.html#method_save

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning for those who are using the PHP built-in web server (as I got trapped, it might help others):

From the PHP doc:

> The web server runs a only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

It means that even if you close the session properly, you'll still end up stailing with one connection at once.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php