# Multiple Ajax request for PHP framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I meet a trouble, that is I can't request 2 ajax at the same time with framework (Symfony)

Here is my code:

JQuery:

```
function doAjax1()
{
    $.ajax({
       url:  "server1.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: {
           id: 1,
       },
       success: function(){

       },
    });
}

function doAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
       url:  "server.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: {
           id: 1,
       },
       success: function(){

       },
    });
}
```

PHP Server:

```
sleep(10);
echo "Done 10s";
```

PHP Server1:

```
sleep(1);
echo "Done 1s";
```

First, I call `doAjax()` and second, `doAjax1()`.

Without any framework, `doAjax1()` take about **1s**, and `doAjax()` take about **10s**, exactly what I want.

But with symfony 1.4 framework, doAjax1() take about **11s**, and doAjax() take about **10s**, it's seem `doAjax()` completed, `doAjax1()` call later.

Is there any safe solution for me?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you call `doAjax()` and `doAjax1()`?

Comment: Please provide your server configuration.

Comment: Notice: you should not use Symfony 1.4 - it is deprecated. Please use Symfony 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

*Following examples are given for Symfony2 but the problem is the same, and the solution too.*

This can be related to the session lock that Symfony operates on controller action. It it well described here :

- http://blog.alterphp.com/2012/08/how-to-deal-with-asynchronous-request.html
- http://garethmccumskey.blogspot.fr/2009/10/php-session-write-locking-and-how-to.html

The trick is : **if you don't need to write in session during your action, free session lock as early as possible** !

Here is 2 related questions :

- [How do I kill a session in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351297/how-do-i-kill-a-session-in-symfony2)
- [Concurrent operation using AJAX in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763172/concurrent-operation-using-ajax-in-symfony2)

Comment: Thank you. Your links are useful for me.

Comment: The first link helped me. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to control ajax calls one after another,
but don't think it will solve your performance issue with simphony, just a recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that cause is your server configuration. It's looks like your PHP cannot execute more than 1 request in the same time. My suggestion is configure PHP workers.