# Symfony2 firewall takes ages

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with Symfony2 firewall component taking ages on some requests.

I've noticed that it mainly happens during AJAX requests, and very specific ones - when I search for an entity using LIKE %..% statements in doctrine (not sure it matters, but that's what I noticed ;)).

Calling the same URL a little later (1 or 2s later) results in "normal" firewall processing time.

I am not using any external data sources for authentication, everything is stored in PostgreSQL.

Look at the following timeline:

[image: timeline]

Is there a way to debug the firewall directly?

My config looks like this:

```
security:
firewalls:
    admin_area:
        provider: db_users
        pattern: ^/admin
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
          login_path: /admin/login
          check_path: /admin/login-check
        logout: 
          path: /admin/logout
          target: /admin
        switch_user: { role: ROLE_SUPERADMIN, parameter: _become_user }

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ~
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/clip-manager/clip/encode/*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login-check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN_LOGIN, ADMIN_AREA] }

providers:
    db_users:
        entity: { class: Webility\Bundle\AppUserBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

encoders:
    Webility\Bundle\AppUserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:          sha256
        iterations:         3
        encode_as_base64:   false

acl:
    connection: default
```

I am using `Symfony\SecurityBundle` and `JMSSecurityExtraBundle`.

Comment: Try using an actual IP address (instead of hostname) for your database server. http://12wiki.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/why-does-symfony-2-firewall-take-so.html

Comment: Are there many AJAX requests processing at same time ot it's the only one ?

Comment: Yes, it's the only one. Although... It's a live search, ie. search as user types (with 100ms delay when user stopped typing) and any previous AJAX requests are aborted. But it indeed may be possible that the requests are aborted but they are still being processed by the server.

Comment: Yes, @PéCé, you've put me on the right track. Fast concurrent AJAX request were slowing it down. I rewrote the LIKE %..% queries to elasticsearch and it's working properly now.

Comment: So you should have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351297/how-do-i-kill-a-session-in-symfony2 Many concurrent requests from the same client (actually using same PHP session) can poduce a bottle neck effect, my solution is here : http://blog.alterphp.com/2012/08/how-to-deal-with-asynchronous-request.html

Comment: isn't doctrine caching the results? if that is true, then it would make sense that it goes fast on the second call... (I also think like takes pretty long)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and want to share the solution with you guys.

[image: Server Response Time increase]

Problem caused by, Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall ~ 107406 ms

[image: Application Timeline]

Solution;

On our case the problem was session handler that we were use on php.ini file.

Previous configuration;

```
session.save_handler = files
```

New configuration;

```
;session.save_handler = files

session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11212"
```

I changed the session handler to memcached. As I already using memcached I needed second instance of memcached or as I implemented additional port listened by memcached solved that issue;

To run memcached to listen two ports, I edit memcached.conf

Previous configuration;

```
-p 11211
-l 127.0.0.1
```

New configuration

```
#-p 11211
#-l 127.0.0.1

-l 127.0.0.1:11211
-l 127.0.0.1:11212
```

and just restarting memcached instance, memcached started to listen two ports on same instance.

```
service memcached restart
```

To validate that memcached listens and responds on new ports you can run telnet command;

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
telnet 127.0.0.1 11212
```

expected output is;

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

The result is very fast application;

[image: Final Application Timeline]

I hope this solution would help you.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather unusual behaviour (unless you're doing something, well... unusual ;).

Try using one of the PHP profilers to see what's going on. I can recommend [XHProf](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof) with [XHProf GUI](http://blog.preinheimer.com/index.php?/archives/355-A-GUI-for-XHProf.html). It's easy to set up and use.

I'm just guessing, but the problem might be related to the database query you mentioned. Check if fields used in a query have appropriate indexes set.

Edit: I accidentally stumbled on this article linked from the Symfony blog: http://12wiki.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/why-does-symfony-2-firewall-take-so.html

It seems to be a DNS issue.

Comment: Yes, I found that article before but unfortunately it wasn't a solution for me :(

Comment: This article work for me using Symfony 4.4 and MariaDB.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different session handler. I had the same issue in my Vagrant box. Not sure what caused it. See http://ctors.net/2014/04/21/symfony_slow_in_vagrant for details.