# Symfony2: Very Slow Session Handling

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, session, symfony-2.8

I'm seeing very slow session related MySQL queries in my production environment, using Symfony2 (2.8.22), AWS EC2 and RDS. I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425786/symfony2-intermittent-high-response-time-slow-sessionhandlerproxyread-compl) a while back, when I was using the default Symfony file system session handler. I'm now using the MySQL handler, which is perhaps even more problematic.

These slow lookups have been particularly aggravating over the pas 12hrs or so, during which time the average throughput of my application was about 80-90 requests per minute.

Other MySQL queries seem perfectly performant, and the issue seems to be isolated to session handling. On other transactions, I might see `MySQL sessions delete`, which also takes 60%-90% of the total transaction time. One answer in my previous question proposed that the slowness might be due to session locking, in which case I'd ask: is there anything I can do to speed this process up? ~20sec to handle sessions is unacceptable.

I've attached a couple reports from New Relic that illustrate the hang ups.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm reposting here something along the comment I made on your Symfony issue.

I believe you must have *concurrent* requests in your application, for example Ajax polling requests. Those requests can happen while the website is open in several browsers tabs or windows, the session get locked in one, and the ajax requests from other tabs get blocked.
You should consider adding `session_write_close()` in your Ajax call to release the lock, if you are not writing anything to the session in your controller.